# CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, azure, kendo-ui, cors

I am using asp mvc 4 and trying to download a file based on a dynamically created.

To do this I am using Kendo UI below downloads a pdf when called:

```
    var generatePDF = function () {
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#property"), { paperSize: "A4", forcePageBreak: ".page-break" })
                     .then(function (group) { kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Converted PDF.pdf"); });
    }
```

No images are being downloaded. The console provides the message

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myStorage.blob.core.windows.net/mySetPath/Large/lounge.JPG. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49878' is therefore not allowed access.

I did a test using [placekitten](http://placekitten.com/g/200/300) and the image downloaded without the above error.

This leads me to believe its simply a permissions issue on the storage container so I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services) and applied the following:

Allowed origins: 127.0.0.1
Allowed Verbs: GET
Allowed headers: x-ms-* (I also tried *)
Exposed headers: x-ms-* (I also tried *)
Maximum age (seconds): 10

But I still get the same error. I have also tried deploying my site on Azure but the error is not resolved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's a CORS issue - look up CORS - the issue can only be fixed on the **server**

Comment: Try with `*` for allowed origins value. You have set `127.0.0.1` as allowed origin and your application is accessed via `localhost` so there's a mismatch there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable CORS for Blob service in the Azure Portal.

1. Go to the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com).
2. Navigate to your Storage account.
3. Click CORS in the **BLOB SERVICE** menu.

[image]

4. Enter each URL in the empty **Allowed Origins** text box.
5. Click **SAVE**

[image]

Comment: I have made the alterations you have suggested but i still get the message: Access to Image at 'myImage' from origin 'https://myImageBlobContainer' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49878' is therefore not allowed access. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to enter an asterisk `*` in `Allowed origins` to specify that all origin domains are accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this extension:

Add **CORS** `chrome extension` into your chrome browser:

[Add CORS extension into your browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

[image: CORS Extension]

**After adding this my problem has been solved.**